# Error in the last installation of joomla1.5.23

Tags: joomla

I've got this error after I deleted the installation folder in `c:\xamp\htdocs\joomla15`. This is the error I got when I tried to open the administrator site to log-in to my back-end:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla15\libraries\loader.php on line 71
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla15\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 32
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla15\libraries\loader.php on line 71
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::load() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla15\libraries\loader.php on line 161
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::register() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla15\libraries\loader.php on line 138
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRequest::clean() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla15\libraries\joomla\import.php on line 33

And so on. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
* EARLIER VALUE : var $error_reporting = ‘-1′;
* CHANGED VALUE: var $error_reporting = ’6135′;
```

Set this values in configuration.php file of Joomla